how do cropTreshold mechanism in highcharts work?
i work with Highcharts inside my angular 16 app. i have an api that returns me temperature data to print in a line chart.
i noticed something weird : sometimes the chart.series[0].data[] array containes all the data printed in the graph, and sometimes, when the amount of data is high, the data array is empty. i can't figure out what is the limit (sometimes 1000, sometimes 2000, for now it's very random).
i went on the github and tried to see if there was a preprcessing of the chart depending on the data put in the series, but didn't manage to get my answer. can anyone please tell me if there is a rule that impacts the content of the data array ?

The cropThreshold option in Highcharts controls the number of points that are allowed to be plotted outside the visible plot area before the series is cropped for performance reasons. If the number of points exceeds the cropThreshold, points outside the plot area are not rendered to improve performance.
There is also the turboThreshold option which sets a limit on the number of data points that can be processed in an optimized mode. If the number of points exceeds the turboThreshold, Highcharts switches to a simplified processing mode to boost performance, but it restricts the data to simple formats like arrays of numbers.
However, the empty series[0].data array indicates that the boost mode is probably active. You can still refer to series[0].points or just deactivate the boost mode.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e1ms85r9/
Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module
API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.boostThreshold
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.cropThreshold
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.turboThreshold

thank you very much for the answer, i switched to series[0].points to manipulate my points even though i still don't understand why the data array is empty (i explored the docs, i tried a lot of values for boost, treshold...)

Hi @user1436883, It's really hard to answer without looking into your code. Could you reproduce this situation in a simple live example using only your chart config and mocked data?

Hi, sorry but i can't copy my organizarion's code on external platforms (we have tools that can detect that and i could be in trouble). all i can say is that this behaviour is very random (sometimes data[] is populated and sometimes not. and even when i use the points[] array, i have problems, i put my data in an ag-grid to view the data used by the graph, and for example i have a situation where i have 11308 lines in the grid and 788 points in the graph. and i dont preprocess the data. all i wanted to know is if there is any mechanism that limits the number of data or points.

I'm not forcing you to share your exact code, but just to reproduce the same problem with minimal chart configuration and mocked data. The two most likely factors that can results in an empty data array are activated boost module and or-grouping in stock charts: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping

thank you, i disabled the boost mode and now my data and points arrays are correct.
